# Deployment Spring MVC application in JBOSS 7.1.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, deployment, jboss

I'm stuck for days in how to deploy my web application on server JBOSS 7.1.1. I already tried a lot of things but so far I didn't have any success.

In Jetty or Tomcat Server my application is running normally, but when I try with JBoss or Deploy in OpenShift, it doesn't work and there is no error messages on the log.

This is my Log:

```
11:24:48,705 INFORMAÇÕES [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
11:24:48,939 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
11:24:48,994 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
11:24:49,797 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
11:24:49,797 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:24:49,807 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
11:24:49,813 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
11:24:49,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
11:24:49,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:24:49,845 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
11:24:49,898 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:24:49,926 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
11:24:49,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
11:24:49,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
11:24:49,939 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
11:24:49,943 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
11:24:49,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:24:50,037 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:24:50,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
11:24:50,172 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
11:24:50,460 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-8) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
11:24:50,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
11:24:50,648 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:9999
11:24:50,656 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\eclipse\servers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
11:24:50,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found eatpiz.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called eatpiz.war.dodeploy
11:24:50,791 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:24:50,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "eatpiz.war"
11:24:53,538 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

11:24:53,553 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

11:24:53,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
11:24:53,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
11:24:53,890 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eatpiz]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [br.com.maven.pizzaria.Aplicacao@55077118, br.com.maven.pizzaria.SegurancaAplicacao@5b920a44]
11:24:54,076 INFORMAÇÕES [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) para o contexto '/eatpiz'
11:24:55,739 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
11:24:56,585 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eatpiz]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11:24:56,587 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
11:24:56,590 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 08 11:24:56 BRT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
11:24:56,724 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Found 8 annotated classes in package [br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes]
11:24:57,392 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
11:24:57,585 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.log.MLog] (MSC service thread 1-2) MLog clients using log4j logging.
11:24:57,615 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing c3p0-0.9.2.1 [built 20-March-2013 10:47:27 +0000; debug? true; trace: 10]
11:24:57,705 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-2) Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
11:24:57,713 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
11:24:57,774 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
11:24:57,776 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
11:24:57,778 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
11:24:57,902 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
11:24:57,977 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hgfdvm9fo16s5ksw6rqp|77e46a1b, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hgfdvm9fo16s5ksw6rqp|77e46a1b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzaria, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
11:24:58,263 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
11:24:58,269 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11:24:58,453 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
11:24:58,877 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
11:25:01,957 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000230: Schema export complete
11:25:02,518 WARN  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker] (MSC service thread 1-2) [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 107.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
11:25:02,540 WARN  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker] (MSC service thread 1-2) [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 89.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
11:25:03,083 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (MSC service thread 1-2) Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@19bee2be, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@32724d8d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6b8685a8, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3dc3b2aa, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4a751562, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4025b207, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@377ab3, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7182f76f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@43183526, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@336ed891, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@499ab329, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2bf883ca]
11:25:03,131 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/clientes],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.ClienteController.index(org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,133 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/clientes/pizza/{nomePizza}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.ClienteController.index(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,135 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/contatos/email/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Email br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.ContatoController.buscarEmail(java.lang.Long)
11:25:03,136 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/contatos/email],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.ContatoController.salvarEmail(br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Email,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,139 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/contatos/email/{id}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.ContatoController.deletarEmail(java.lang.Long)
11:25:03,141 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/contatos/telefone/{id}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.ContatoController.deletarTelefone(java.lang.Long)
11:25:03,143 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/contatos/telefone],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.ContatoController.salvarTelefone(br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Telefone,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,144 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/contatos/telefone/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Telefone br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.ContatoController.buscarTelefone(java.lang.Long)
11:25:03,146 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/contatos],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.ContatoController.listarContatos(org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,150 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/ingredientes],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.IngredienteController.salvarIngrediente(br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Ingrediente,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,152 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/ingredientes/{id}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.IngredienteController.deletarIngrediente(java.lang.Long)
11:25:03,153 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/ingredientes],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.IngredienteController.listarIngredientes(org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,154 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/ingredientes/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Ingrediente br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.IngredienteController.buscarIndregiente(java.lang.Long)
11:25:03,156 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/pizzas/{pizzaId}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.PizzaController.deletarPizza(java.lang.Long)
11:25:03,157 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/pizzas],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.PizzaController.listarPizzas(org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,158 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/pizzas],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.PizzaController.salvarPizza(org.springframework.ui.Model,br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Pizza,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
11:25:03,159 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/pizzas/{pizzaId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Pizza> br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.PizzaController.buscarPizza(java.lang.Long)
11:25:03,161 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/home],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.PizzariaController.homePizzaria(org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,162 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/cadastrar],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.PizzariaController.showFormCadastrar(org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,163 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/editar],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.PizzariaController.editarPizzaria(br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Pizzaria,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:25:03,164 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/cadastrar],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.PizzariaController.salvarPizzaria(br.com.maven.pizzaria.modelo.entidades.Pizzaria,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:25:03,165 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/pizzarias/editar],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.maven.pizzaria.configuracoes.controladores.PizzariaController.showFormEditar(org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:25:03,177 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped URL path [/clientes] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
11:25:03,178 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped URL path [/pizzarias/login] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
11:25:03,178 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
11:25:03,192 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped URL path [/static/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
11:25:03,338 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (MSC service thread 1-2) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 08 11:24:56 BRT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
11:25:03,386 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6799 ms
11:25:03,389 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eatpiz]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
11:25:03,390 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-2) FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
11:25:03,403 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-2) FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 13 ms
11:25:03,413 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /eatpiz
11:25:03,420 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:25:03,421 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 15031ms - Started 382 of 459 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
11:25:03,504 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "eatpiz.war"
```

When I try to access my initial page ([localhost:8080/eatpiz/](http://localhost:8080/eatpiz/)), I receive a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: what is the problem ? The log seems ok.

Comment: When I access my initial view or another mapping view, I receive 404 error.

Comment: Could you provide the initial URL ?

Comment: At first I'm trying to deploy in my computer. Should be: http://localhost/eatpiz/ (index.jsp point to mapping http://localhost/eatpiz/clientes).

Comment: try localhost:8080/clientes/ or localhost:8080/eatpiz/clientes/

Comment: I'm sorry I said wrong, my first view it's localhost:8080/eatpiz/ and index.jsp redirect to localhost:8080/eatpiz/clientes.
I already tryied to change my http port avoiding conflict erros, but I didn't get any results.

Comment: what do you get if you try http://localhost:8080/ ?

Comment: Furthermore, you must have a marker file (eatpiz.war.deployed) in your deployments directory. 
The suffix (.deployed, .failed) represents the status of the deployment.
Could you please confirm it?

Comment: In localhost:8080 I get the initial page of JBoss ("Welcome to AS 7"....).
My deployments directory is empty, but my another web application which is running normally in JBoss doesn't have nothing also in deployments directory. 
This last one doesn't use Spring Framework and is running, I'm thinking if it's possible be a issue between JBoss and Spring.